# Content Security Policy with google closure

Tags: javascript, json, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I am trying to enable CSP for my web application. My policy is something like:

> "default-src 'self' gap: cdvfile:;"

I am using google closure for javascript. However without javascript optimization, My js is blocked because of :

> goog.json.parse uses eval()

If I compile my code with closure compiler, there is no issue as in advance compile, eval() is not used. (JSON.parse is used)

I know, as a workaround, I can use `sha256-.....` or `nonce=....`.

Is there any other way, I can use CSP without using `sha..` or `nonce..`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you add `goog.json.USE_NATIVE_JSON = true;` to your code that it won't use `eval`.

Comment: I want to try this method. But, not sure where to add this. Could you please let me know, where should I add this `goog.json.USE_NATIVE_JSON = true;` ?